# Best practice for establishing new local web development directory on Mac

Tags: macos, web

This has bugged me for a long time, and I would like to get a consensus on what the best practice is.

- Assume you are going to develop a website.
- Assume you are using a Mac as your development platform.
- Assume you want to develop your new web pages privately/locally on your Mac before publishing the finished files.

Do you create your development folder in /Library/WebServer/Documents
and then modify the permissions so you can actually do work in that directory?
In other words:

```
    sudo mkdir -p /Library/WebServer/Documents/MyNewSite
    sudo chmod 775 /Library/WebServer/Documents/MyNewSite
```

That just seems awkward to me.
I expect that there is some preferred location for new local web files, that does not require tweaking permissions preset by the natural installation of the OS.

If there is some document that describes the official best practice, I'd sure appreciate a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

You generally do your development in your home directory. The default configuration should allow you to use `~/Sites`, which you can access at `http://localhost/~yourusername`

Comment: ~/Sites is no longer supported in the standard install of Mac OS X. You can take extra steps to re-enable it, including editing 

/etc/apache2/users/\`whoami\`.conf

But those steps seem even more obtuse than "fixing" the permissions as described above. Sigh.

Comment: @user749105 Really? Huh. I guess I've had this one install for so long, I still have the old default configuration. Anyhow, I would still recommend configuring Apache to serve your files out of your home directory; your home directory should always be where your files go. If you ever need to migrate your files to a fresh installation, it is best if all of your own files are in your home directory, to distinguish them from system files or machine-specific files.